# Is it possible to perform one query linking to tables on 2 databases with Dapper?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, dapper

I have 2 databases, a master and a company. Both databases are on the same server currently but will eventually be on different servers. Is it possible to perform a query that joins tables across databases in dapper? My application is Asp.NET Core and the databases are MariaDB (so basically MySQL).

Here is an example of a query I'm trying to perform:

```
select a.username, b.name from company.user a join master.lookup_user_type b on a.user_type_id = b.id
```

Maybe I'm confused what my actual question is, maybe I just need to figure out how to have one conncetion string that references multiple databases.

Comment: In Dapper you just use raw SQL queries so it's possible.

Comment: dapper *core* issues whatever query you give it; if you're using contrib/rainbow/etc, you'll have to be more specific; but even in *core*, there is support for queries that map into multiple types based on a horizontal split, or you can use `QueryMultiple` if you are doing vertical splits over multiple queries; can you show the type of query you had in mind?

Comment: @MarcGravell I edited my question to include a sample query

Comment: Your query looks right; are you getting an error?

Comment: @Kristen then yes, that'll work fine, as long as your RDBMS (mysql) supports it; dapper doesn't understand the query, and frankly: doesn't care

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to perform a query across two different databases on the same server, as long as the user you're logging in as has permission to access both databases.. Assuming your databases are named `company` and `master`, then your query looks correct.

If your databases are on two different servers, you will need to use [federated tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-federatedx/).